# Condition for $n-1$ derivatives of a polynomial to be greater than $0$

Tags: polynomials

I have an $n$ degree polynomial in variable $x.$ Is there any condition, which if satisfied will guarantee that the first $n-1$ derivatives of the nth degree polynomial at a particular given point are positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask the question for $x=0$, the answer will be "all coefficients must be positive" (this is easy to show by setting $x=0$ in all derivatives).

If you ask it for any $a$, this translates to "all coefficients of $P(x+a)$ must be positive". But the computation of the coefficients of $P(x+a)$ is tedious:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i(x+a)^i=\sum_{i=0}^n p_i\sum_{j=0}^i\binom ija^{i-j}x^j.$$